# JavaScript refactored as OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

How can I refactor the code below as OOP?

I don't expect you to give me a full re-write here, rather I am seeking advice on how to approach and convert my code into OOP.

This is something new to me. If you can just show the thought process behind and perhaps just add an initial code refactor, I'll start studying and implementing it further. Insights on best practices are welcome as well.

```
$(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/data",
    success: res => {
        console.log(res);
        let data = res;
        //console.log(data.guests[0].firstName);

        let Greeting = () => {

            let getFirstName = data.guests.map(name => name.firstName);
            let getHotelName = data.hotels.map(name => name.company);
            let getRoomNumber = data.guests.map(number => number.reservation.roomNumber);

            let handleSubmit = () => {
                $("#form").submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    let room = $('#selectRoom').val();
                    let name = $('#selectName').val();
                    let hotel = $('#selectHotel').val();
                    let greetGuest = `${time} ${name} and welcome to ${hotel} your ${room} is now ready for you. Enjoy your stay, let us know if you need anything.`;
                    console.log(greetGuest);
                    //append to Dom
                    $('#message').append(greetGuest);
                });
            };
            handleSubmit()

        };
        Greeting();
    }, //success ends
    error: err => console.log(err)
});
});
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: This is more of a code review question than a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Personally I don't recommend OOP for javascript. It can be useful in some cases, but in general it just leads to extra boilerplate and a Functional Programming style is more suitable.

Comment: Where do you think do you can you apply OOP here, and why do you think you need it? The code already uses objects all over the place, where they are suitable.

Comment: @DuncanThacker You cannot really avoid objects in JS. You can (and should) avoid the "put everything into a class" mentality of Java, but there's nothing wrong with functional OOP in general.

Comment: @Bergi is correct. OO vs Functional is a false dichotomy. The code is very decent as is and introducing classes would definitely reduce its quality.

Comment: I am just trying to learn the concept of OOP and how would I go about refactoring the code snippet.

Comment: @DuncanThacker - Saying you don't recommend OOP in Javascript is a pretty silly statement.  First off, Javascript is OOP at its core.  You can't avoid it.  Second, a given piece of code either lends itself to an OOP design or not -that's more a property of the problem at hand than it is the language being used.  So, saying OOP in Javascript is not recommended is downright silly.

Comment: I'd suggest you study the basic concepts of object oriented programming.  Reading the equivalent of a few chapters of a book in online resources should familiarize yourself with the basic concepts.  OOP is about recognizing situations that lend themselves to OOP, not about forcing a given problem into an OOP design.  We can't really teach you OOP here, nor is your particular code snippet particularly appropriate for a new and OOP design.  If this is working code here, then you can post at https://codereview.stackexchange.com to see if people have suggestions for how to improve it.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00 . I just joined codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Please be sure you are familiar with the rules at codereview before posting as the rules are very specific and are enforced.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I respectfully disagree with your characterisation but don't want to disrupt this question; could we continue this discussion elsewhere? Not sure what the etiquette is on SO. Thanks!

Comment: @DuncanThacker - Online chat would be the only place stack overflow offers to go to discuss this, but if you're going to stand by such an outrageous generalization that all Javascript code is better written in a functional style without any OOP design, then I don't care to discuss it with you further - no point.  Bye.

Comment: @jfriend00 - If you look at my comment, I clearly said "It can be useful in some cases", so I think you may have misunderstood my meaning! All the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of OOP is to encapsulate functionality into objects, such that each object has a specific set of properties and behavior attached to it. The provided snippet can be modified to have a `Greeting` class that has a `handleSubmit` method with the properties described inside the arrow function of the AJAX callback. However, based on the layout, you'd probably only have an instance, essentially making OOP useless here.

You perform an AJAX request which fetches all the data for each greeting. You then map the data into separate arrays that each have specific per-guest data. If you really want to use classes, this can be refactored into something like:

```
class HotelGuest {
  constructor(a, b, c) {
    this.firstName = a;
    this.hotelName = b;
    this.roomNum = c;
  }

  // Add ${time} as necessary, because I only see it once and do not know its purpose
  get greeting(){
    return this.firstName + " and welcome to " + this.hotelName +
      " your " + this.roomNum + " is now ready for you. Enjoy your stay, let us know if you need anything.";
  }
}

var guestsInfo = [];

$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/data",

    success: data => {
      data.guests.forEach((guest, i) => guestsInfo.push(new HotelGuest(guest.firstName, data.hotels[i].company, guest.reservation.roomNumber)));
    },

    error: err => console.log(err)
  });
});
```

All of the guests and important info can be found into `guestsInfo`. Each element follows the layout of the `HotelGuest` class. To get a guest's greeting, just access the `.greeting` property. It'll change based on the guest's data.

For more information on classes and their syntax in ES6, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes